# Convert a Collider into a trigger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a 2D Action-Platformer in Unity, I have a crawl function that activates when the play presses S but I need it to convert the head collider into a trigger so that when the player is crawling into a tight space the game picks up on that and prevents them from standing again which would cause glitches. How do I convert the head collider into a trigger

Bonus: The player sticks to other colliders so if anyone knows how to fix that it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't try to convert the collider into a trigger, have a head collider and a trigger around the head, and deactive the collider when the player is crawling and activate the trigger. And vice versa when he is standing.

Comment: You could also do a raycast from the ground upwards or from his head upwards to ensure there is enough space to stand, if not then prevent the standing action

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a collider into a trigger during runtime using the `isTrigger` property of the collider, like so:

```
private Collider collider ;

void Start() {
    // Assuming this script goes on the head gameobject
    collider = this.GetComponent<Collider>();
}
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col) {
    this.collider.isTrigger = true;
}
void OnTriggerExit(Collider other) {
    this.collider.isTrigger = false;
}
```

@JanR suggested solution is probably cleaner. But as your question was on how to convert a collider into a trigger I thought it was worth an answer.

Anyway, depending on your scene geometry this can always get messy.
You will have problems when having two or more colliders interacting with your head collider/trigger.

You can circunvent this problem by keeping a list of interacting colliders, youd have to use `OnCollisionEnter` to register the collider into the list and `OnCollisionExit` to unregister it. Then you would only reactivate the collider when the list is empty.

That's why most of us use raycast instead of colliders/triggers to cope with this kind of situations.